# Given a pair of images, how to automatically create an animation sequence morphing one image into the other?

Tags: automation, imagemagick, photoshop, animated-gif, gimp

Is there a programmatic way to convert two images into an animation sequence (e.g., an animated GIF) like the following example?

[image: From memrise.com, showing an animated GIF between two images]

This image sequence, taken from a http://memrise.com course, doesn't seem to have manually-edited frames, but seems automatically transformed using some kind shape morphing algorithm. Is there a common term used to describe such an animation or algorithm? Is there a feature in ImageMagick or Photoshop/Gimp that generates such animations, given a pair of images?

Ideally the technique could be scriptable so I could create animations for several pairs of start-end images.

Edit: I have just been told about Gimp's tool under Filters->Animation->Blend, which appears to do the same thing as jQuery morph: each frame `i` is `start + (finish - start)/N*i`. In other words, you're transitioning each pixel independently from the start value to the finish value, without any shape morphing. The example gives is more complicated, as it modifies the contours of both images to achieve its compelling effect.

Other examples:

- http://static.memrise.com/uploads/mems/32000121024054535.gif
- http://static.memrise.com/uploads/mems/225428000121109232837.gif

Comment: like this? http://codeassembly.com/examples/gallery/index.html

Comment: Not like that, @daniel, edited the question to indicate something more complicated (that morphs the image contours and colors) than straightforward pixelwise blending.

Comment: None of the answers allow scripting the process *and* having automatic control point creation. :(

Comment: @Evi1M4chine I'm disappointed that I couldn't find a tool that made control point creation relatively easy. I'd have been overjoyed to find one which automated this! I haven't looked much since then, but the need still exists.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: I needed it for interpolating image series to higher frame rate video. So my logic went like this: MPEG-like algorithms have motion compensation. which uses motion detection. So if I extract the motion vectors, I should be able to automatically use them as pairs of control points. I found a modified version of ffmpeg which could extract the motion vectors. and a simple script should be able to convert them to control point pairs, to be used by e.g. shapemorph. But it was not worth the work for me. … Maybe in the future. …

Comment: @AhmedFasih There is a solution now. look at my answer :)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine The future is now! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a tool that doesn't require setting manual keypoints and is not restricted to a domain (like faces). Anyway, the images have to be similar (e.g. two faces or two cars from the same perspective).

https://github.com/kallaballa/Poppy

There is also a [web-version](https://viel-zu.org/poppy) created with emscripten.

[image: flame to glyph morphing]

I generated the above animation using following command line:

`poppy flame.png glyph.png flame.png`

Comment: I am repeatedly editing this because results are gradually getting better :)

Comment: Very impressive! I look forward to seeing if the algorithm can be made invariant to rotation and scale!

Comment: There is now a an auto-align parameter, but it is far from perfect.

Comment: Indeed your project lookś great.
You migth go to the stack exchange Software Recommendations site and write a question and self-answer it with poppy: it should get you some more visibility. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! I did exactly that: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83153/what-command-line-software-is-there-for-fully-automatic-image-morphing

Comment: Hey, great work! Have you looked at the motion compensation algorithms used in modern video codecs (like x265)? Because those seem to be specifically designed to recognize common patterns regardless of any transformation (translation, rotation, scaling, and even tilting) in order to only store one copy of the data and the transformation matrix.) … Other than that, … if non-computer-savy youtubers can use deepfake NN to prank their friends, maybe using a neurnal net for the non-algorithmically-solvable problem parts is approachable by you to.

Comment: Interesting ideas. But at the moment I am working on this: https://viel-zu.org/poppy/.  It's an emscripten port of poppy. not very mobile friendly yet :)

Comment: Would you have any examples of NN solutions for the transformation problem?

Comment: @Evi1M4chine I implemented an auto transform algorithm based on procrustes analysis. Works very well!

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, since ImageMagick is mentioned, for anyone who comes here from google it may be worth looking at [this imagemagick plugin called shapemorph](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/shapemorph/).

Answer (score 1):

GIMP can't do that directly, but over the years a series of (now poorly maintaind) plug-ins to do that where released by third parties. The keyword for searching for this is "morph" - you should find a bunch of stand alone programs to do that as well, from "gratis" to full fledged Free Software, such as [xmorph](http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: After seeing how complicated and hands-on current offerings like xmorph [1] and GAP (for Gimp) [2] are, I decided to stick with unanimated drawings.

[1] http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/home/gourlay/public_html/Xmorph/pub/examples/Tutorial/
[2] http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaSz8WNKjD4

Comment: @AhmedFasih maybe you should then change the accepted answer to the one referencing poppy, since it does what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Given pairs of vector files (.wmf extension) it is possible to use linear interpolation of shapenodes in Visual Basic for Applications to create frames for GIF animations , though this would take along time to explain.  For some examples see

http://www.giless.co.uk/animatorMorphGIFs.htm (it is like a slideshow)

I have made some improvements since then, as well!