# Video Morph Between Two Images, FFMPEG/Minterpolate

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, video-effects

I am trying to make a quick and easy morph video using two frames (png images) with ffmpeg's minterpolate filter, in a bash script on Ubuntu Linux. The intent is to use the morphs as transitions between similar video in a different video editor later.

It will work on 3+ frames/images, but **fails using just 2 frames/images.**

### First the code that works: 3 frames

This is using three 1080p png files:

`test01_01.png`
`test01_02.png`
`test01_03.png`

```
input01="test01_%02d.png"

ffmpeg -y -fflags +genpts -r 30 -i $input01 -vf "setpts=100*PTS,minterpolate=fps=24:scd=none" -pix_fmt yuv420p "test01.mp4"
```

This takes a bit of processing time, then creates a 414kb, roughly three second mp4 video of a morph starting with the first frame, morphing to the second, then morphing to the third.

### The code that fails: 2 frames

This is using just two of the same 1080p png files:

`test02_01.png`
`test02_02.png`

```
input01="test02_%02d.png"

ffmpeg -y -fflags +genpts -r 30 -i $input01 -vf "setpts=100*PTS,minterpolate=fps=24:scd=none" -pix_fmt yuv420p "test02.mp4"
```

This almost immediately creates a 262 **byte** corrupt mp4 file. There are no differences except the number of frames.

### Things I've tried:

I have tried this with the Ubuntu default repo version of ffmpeg, and the static 64bit 5.0 and git-20220108-amd64 versions, all with the same result.

I have also tried with a 2-frame mp4 file as the input, with the same result.

### Thoughts?

Is this a bug in ffmpeg or am I doing something wrong?

I am also open to any suggestions for creating a morph like this using other Linux-compatible software.

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: It's not documented, but it looks like `minterpolate` filter requires at least 3 input frames.

Comment: why not use a dedicated morphing tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734714/given-a-pair-of-images-how-to-automatically-create-an-animation-sequence-morphi/71198395#71198395

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not documented, but it looks like `minterpolate` filter requires at least 3 input frames.

We may create a longer video using 5 input frames, and keep the relevant part.

For getting the same output as applying Minterpolate filter with only two input images, we may use the following solution:

- Define two input streams:
  Set `test02_01.png` as the first input and `test02_02.png` as the second input.
- Loop each image at least twice, using `-stream_loop`
  (`test02_01.png` is repeated twice and `test02_02.png` is repeated 3 times).
- Set the input frame rate to 0.3 fps (it is equivalent to `-r 30` and `setpts=100*PTS`).
  The input arguments are as follows: `-r 0.3 -stream_loop 1 -i test02_01.png -r 0.3 -stream_loop 2 -i test02_02.png`.
- Concatenate the two input streams using `concat` filter.
- Apply `minterpolate` filer to the concatenated output.
  The output of the above stage is a video with few redundant seconds at the beginning, and few redundant seconds at the end.
- Apply `trim` filter for keeping the relevant part.
  Add `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` at the end (as recommended when using trim filter).

---

Suggested command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 0.3 -stream_loop 1 -i test02_01.png -r 0.3 -stream_loop 2 -i test02_02.png -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v]minterpolate=fps=24:scd=none,trim=3:7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -pix_fmt yuv420p test02.mp4
```

---

Sample output (as animate GIF):
[image]

---

`test02_01.png`:
[image]

`test02_02.png`:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Never would have figured that out! Thank you! And great choice of demo images! :3

Comment: I want to make this work for a variable number of files. I tried this, but it doesn't work. 
```
ffmpeg -y -r 0.3 -stream_loop 1 -i %d.jpg -r 0.3 -stream_loop 2 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v]minterpolate=fps=24:scd=none,trim=3:7,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -pix_fmt yuv420p test02.mp4
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Christian Try starting with simple command first: `ffmpeg -y -r 0.3 -i %03d.jpg -vf "minterpolate=fps=24:scd=none" -pix_fmt yuv420p test02.mp4`. Most of the complexities of the above answer are due to the fact that `minterpolate` filter fails to work with just two input frames.

Comment: Awesome, that works. However, the effect itself is extremely mushy.. When it morphs from 1 image to another, the time in between it looks actually pretty scare and distracts from the actual image. Is it possible, to a) make the animation a bit clener and b) make the animation faster while showing the actual image longer?

Comment: And one last question. It seems like the pattern %d.jpg only takes images 0-9. What pattern do I have to use if I want to read picture 0-999.jpg?

Comment: @Christian about the morph, I didn't know. For file pattern, in Linux try glob pattern. In Windows, I don't know - rename the files to 001.jpg, 002.jpg, ... And use %03d. Using concat demuxer with a text file may also work